# java.io.Closeable: why throwing RuntimeException in close() works?

Tags: java, exception, java-7

I do not know why this codes compiles on Java 7:

```
class Lamb implements Closeable{
  @Override
  public void close(){
    throw new RuntimeException();   
  } 
}
```

Method close() from Closeable throws IOException. When overriding a method the "throws" declaration must remain the same or use a subclass. 
Now, the RuntimeException is "runtime" so do not need to be declared (I get to this part) BUT it inherits from Exception and not IOException! You can't extend the scope, right?

Comment: Any method can throw any unchecked exception, regardless of `throws` declarations (you said that yourself). It doesn't matter what branch of the hierarchy the unchecked exception belongs to because it's not subject to checking (exactly why it is called an "unchecked" exception).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the "throws" declaration must remain the same or use a subclass.

That's not true. What is true is that the `throws` clause must be the same or *more restrictive*. More restrictive either means throwing a more restrictive type of `Exception` (i.e. a subclass), or *not* declaring that it can throw the exception. Not being able to throw an exception is more restrictive than being able to.

I should also point out that even though this method does not implicitly have `throws IOException` in its `throws` clause, even if it did this would not conflict with `throw new RuntimeException();`. Any method can throw a subclass of `RuntimeException` (aka unchecked exception), no matter what is written after `throws`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any difference whether or not `RuntimeException` inherits from `IOException` because `RuntimeException` doesn't participate in exception checking, as you already admitted in your question.